# Implement jQuery Smart wizard

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I want to implement [jQuery Smart Wizard](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard) to create a form that will let the user input some information. It usually need that all the html is inserted on one page, but I don't know if this is the best approach with wordpress and if it will work well. Is there anyone who have implemented it in his/her theme? I need to figure out how to manage the form submission, I think that the best approach is ajax,but how I save the data after submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this jQuery library myself, but based on a quick glance on the documentation, you could probably just wrap the wizard inside a `<form>` tag and add a custom handler for the `smartWizard` [`onFinish`](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard#event-description) event. When the event is fired, send the form data to server with either [admin ajax](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) or [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

So your html could look something like this,

```
<form id="wizzard-form">
  <div id="wizzard" class="swMain">
    <ul>
      <!-- step li items -->
    </ul>
    <div id="step-n">
      <!-- step input fields -->
    </div>
    <!-- more steps -->
  </div>
</form>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Smart Wizard         
  $('#wizzard').smartWizard({
    onFinish:onFinishCallback
  });

  function onFinishCallback(objs, context){
    if(validateAllSteps()){
      $('#wizzard-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var data = {
          'action': 'my_wizzard_ajax',
          // form data
        };

        jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            alert('You are a wizzard ' + response);
        });
      });
    }
  }        
});
```

PHP to handle ajax saving. Pick a suitable function or write your own custom logic to save the data user sends.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_wizzard_ajax', 'my_wizzard_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_wizzard_ajax', 'my_wizzard_ajax' ); // if available to non logged-in users

function my_wizzard_ajax() {

  // nonce check

  // capabilities check

  // required data exists checks, get data from $_POST super global variable

  if ( $all_good ) {

    // do something
    // wp_insert_post
    // wp_update_post
    // wp_update_meta
    // wp_update_user
    // update_user_meta

    wp_send_json_success( 'Harry' );

  } else {

    wp_send_json_error( 'Rincewind' );

  }

}
```

**N.B** This is by no means a complete example and requires you to fill in the details of the implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try this way to implement the wizard. I think that I will use custom post type with custom post meta to store the form data so the wp internal search can found the required informations if are present.